# Are enum types stored as ints in C#?

Tags: c#

Are enum types stored as ints in C#?

Will the enum below be represented as 0, 1, 2?

If not, what's the lightest way to define an enum?

```
public enum ColumnType
{
    INT,STRING,OBJECT
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'lightest way', memory consumption?

Comment: Minor note; it would be uncommon to UPPERCASE the names; not invalid... Just unusual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=VS.100).aspx)

> The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int.
>
> By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.

So your assumptions are correct. `Enum`s are stored as `int`s and your example will be represented as 0, 1, 2. However, you shouldn't rely on this and *always* refer to them by their assigned name just in case someone overrides the default.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, an `enum` is stored as an `int` by default., as indicated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

You can also specify the underlying type, e.g.:

```
enum Foo : short
{
    Bar,
    Baz
}
```

Although that usually isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

By default yes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type
>   consisting of a set of named constants called the enumerator list.
>   Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any
>   integral type except char. The default underlying type of the
>   enumeration elements is int. By default, the first enumerator has the
>   value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by
>   1.

Answer (score 2):

The default underlying type for an `enum` is an `int`, but different types can be used explicitly. For example, you can use `byte`:

```
enum Days : byte {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx for details.

Answer (score 1):

Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char.
Yes your  enum  be represented as 0,1,2 by default and it is the lightest way to define an enum

How ever you define enum by defining starting value as your requirement and assigning integral values explicitly to each of your enum member as well

Answer (score 1):

The point about underlying types is already well-covered, so I'll add a different context:

At the IL / runtime level, instances of enums *do not exist*. They only exist:

a: to the compiler
b: to the runtime *as a boxed value*
c: in metadata (parameter/field/variable declarations)

At all other times, they are purely the integer-types values (most commonly `int`). The compiler uses enum variables (etc) for static analysis, overload resolution, etc but the opcodes it emits are identical to those it would have emitted for constant / literal integer values; i.e.

```
SomeEnum foo = SomeEnum.WithValueOne;
int bar = 1;
```

will have identical IL (except for the variable type, perhaps).

The only time it gets interesting is if emitting a box operation, or a call like .ToString() etc.

So: as long as you don't box them (store them in an `object` field/etc), then there is (at runtime) no significant difference between an enum or an integer when it comes to storage or performance (unless you use .ToString(), etc)